# Moodle oauth2 auth with google - fields mapping

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, moodle

I need to setup an oauth2 authentication system for Moodle. I already configured all the stuff on the Moodle side and the auth works good. I can create a new user without any problem.
But my nightmare is mapping fields on Moodle side, for instance I need to map externalIds field of google to the id field of Moodle but I spent many hours trying this that seems impossibile.

I already tried to configure manual field mapping on Moodle settings (externalIds -> idnumber or  id -> idnumbers) but not working
I'm using this scopes list: openid profile email

After a lot of try with google oauth2 playground I'm asking your help.

Thansk

I already tried to configure manual field mapping on Moodle settings (externalIds -> idnumber or  id -> idnumbers) but not working

I expecting to register a new user account with all the fields that google already sent me plus externalIds